# Download more than 10000 files from filter added in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have different subfolders in one folder on sharepoint. There 45k records distributed amongts these folders not in any order. We have applied a filter to categorize the files into diffeent categories. Some filters have lesser files (Around 700) and it is getting downloaded easily when i click on select all and download.

Noe the issue is with the filter with categories that have 10000 records or 8000 records. I am not being able to multi select and download these files. When selecting all and download, it is not doing anything.

How to download these files ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use OneDrive sync app to sync files in entire folder.
   [Sync SharePoint and Teams files with your computer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sync-sharepoint-and-teams-files-with-your-computer-6de9ede8-5b6e-4503-80b2-6190f3354a88)
2. You can try to get all the files by running the PowerShell code by following the article below.
   Reference:[Download All Files From a SharePoint Library Programmatically using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/06/download-all-files-from-library-programmatically-using-powershell.html)